# Unwanted top padding on AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, padding, margin

I created a simple dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MyDialogStyle));
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.my_title));
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.my_message));
            builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.my_string1), (dialog, id) -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            });
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.my_string2), (dialog, id) -> dialog.dismiss() );
            builder.create().show();
```

This is my style code:

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorGreyMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/dim_text_size</item>
</style>
```

I had already done it in other past projects.
But this time I do not understand why an unwanted padding is added on the top of the dialog.

[image]

Comment: removeing this parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Dialog" should fix this issue.

Comment: @ImranAli It seems to work. But why I used this code in many other project and it do not happen?

Comment: I don`t know the answer to why. But i just tried your code and there is no extra padding. 
check: https://ibb.co/n0rvnq7